# How do i fix hadoop error when Username has a space in it?

Tags: windows, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

So I am currently using `hadoop-3.3.6` on windows, and I am getting an error that stems from the fact that Hadoop creates a tmp folder and inside it there is the path: `C:\tmp\hadoop-Lenovo I7` and `C:\tmp\hadoop-Lenovo I7\nm-local-dir\usercache\Lenovo I7`, `Lenovo I7` is my user name in windows, but Hadoop cannot read paths with spaces in them, so is there a way to fix this issue with my user name and set it to something else?

putting this code in `core-site.xml` fixes the first link `C:\tmp\hadoop-Lenovo I7`

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hadoop</value>
 </property>
```

But it does not change the second link: `C:\tmp\hadoop-Lenovo I7\nm-local-dir\usercache\Lenovo I7`, it just changes to `C:\tmp\hadoop\nm-local-dir\usercache\Lenovo I7`, but that last folder still stays the same, I have tried stuff like this to change that route specifically

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.nm-local-dir</name>
    <value>C:\tmp\hadoop\nm-local-dir</value>
</property>
```

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.usercache.dir</name>
    <value>C:\tmp\hadoop\nm-local-dir\usercache\Lenovo</value>
</property>
```

or this:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-cache.root-dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache</value>
</property>
```

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-cache.usercache.user-name</name>
    <value>Usuario</value>
</property>
```

but it doesn't work, it could be something along these line but I could also be by changing something so that Hadoop gets my user name as something else but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Try finding the hadoop-env.cmd file, I think, and override HADOOP_USER_NAME